# Python dictionary in descend order

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python and I want to order it in the descending order. I tried to use orderedDict and reserver = True but it didn't work. My code:

```
print user_dictionary
od =  OrderedDict(sorted(user_dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]), reverse = True)
print od
```

However, this bunch of code returned the following results:

```
OrderedDict([(u'1496657429.46', 9.600000000000001), (u'1496657614.45', 10.0), (u'1496657799.16', 9.600000000000001), (u'1496657799.37', 9.600000000000001), ('reserve', True)])
{u'1496657429.46': 9.600000000000001, u'1496657799.37': 9.600000000000001, u'1496657614.45': 10.0, u'1496657799.16': 9.600000000000001}
```

It seems that the order is still the same. How can I change that?

Comment: It is `reverse`, not `reserve`...

Comment: Oh the pitfall of kwargs

Comment: and keep in mind that you are sorting `str`ings, not `float`s.

Comment: Furthermore it is a keyword of `sorted`, not of `OrderedDict`...

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, but the result is the same.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question. The mistake was not only the typo.

Comment: So should i accept your edit in the answer, or should I wait for the question to open again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from your typo in `reverse` as mentioned in the comments, `reverse` is a keyword of `sorted` not `OrderedDict` so you parenthesis game was also weak.
Below you will find a working solution:

```
od = OrderedDict(sorted(user_dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse = True))
```

Comment: `od =  OrderedDict(sorted(user_dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse = True))` And at least format it a bit

Comment: @Ev.Kounis your soutions worked. Posted it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: @JoseRamon The question is on hold. No further answers are accepted. I edited this one.